# Environment variable for nginx conf extrapolation

Tags: nginx, confd

I'm using `confd` to render my configuration files depending on my environments

```
$ ls -R /etc/confd
/etc/confd/:
conf.d  templates

/etc/confd/conf.d:
my_app.toml

/etc/confd/templates:
my_app.tmpl
```

My configurations:

```ini
$ cat /etc/confd/conf.d/my_app.toml
[template]
src = "my_app.tmpl"
dest = "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my_app.conf"
```

```nginx
$ cat /etc/confd/templates/my_app.tmpl
# ...
    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /{{ getenv "/app/entry/point" }}/$1 last;
    }
# ...
```

`confd` runs well

```
$ export APP_ENTRY_POINT="app_dev.php"
$ confd -onetime -backend env
2016-04-15T13:54:29Z 1c682a040707 /usr/local/bin/confd[44]: INFO Backend set to env
2016-04-15T13:54:29Z 1c682a040707 /usr/local/bin/confd[44]: INFO Starting confd
2016-04-15T13:54:29Z 1c682a040707 /usr/local/bin/confd[44]: INFO Backend nodes set to
2016-04-15T13:54:29Z 1c682a040707 /usr/local/bin/confd[44]: INFO Target config /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my_app.conf out of sync
2016-04-15T13:54:29Z 1c682a040707 /usr/local/bin/confd[44]: INFO Target config /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my_app.conf has been updated
```

But the generated file does not get the variable resolved

```nginx
$ cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my_app.conf
# ...
    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ //$1 last;
#                       ^- I should have app_dev.php between the `//`
    }
# ...
```

- Am I doing something wrong here ?
- How can I debug this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike [what is documented](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd/blob/master/docs/quick-start-guide.md#environment-variables), `confd` (0.11.0) `getenv` function does not seem to expect environment variables as path `/app/entry/point`.

The environment variable is indeed kept as is: `APP_ENTRY_POINT`

So the template should simply say:

```nginx
$ cat /etc/confd/templates/my_app.tmpl
# ...
    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /{{ getenv "APP_ENTRY_POINT" }}/$1 last;
    }
# ...
```

There are `-debug` & `-verbose` options to check what is going on

Comment: The page you linked uses `getv`, not `getenv`. Are you sure that this is not the actual error you're experiencing?